# Oracle CONNECT BY PRIOR equivalent in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How to achieve Oraclel's CONNECT BY PRIOR output using LINQ? Basically i need the hierarchy and level using LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't one. LINQ does not have special support for recursive queries.

An approach you can use is to write a method that fetches the top level using a LINQ query, then a method that calls itself recursively to get the children for each of the items received so far. This can result in a lot of small LINQ queries which might not be desiarable.

A different approach is to use a stored procedure containing a recursive query and call that using LINQ.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion and let me try

Comment: I know this is old now, but in case someone comes here.
You can also create a View in Oracle, and then create an Entity that matches the View as though it was a table.