# Return category hierarchy in a string like "cat1 > cat2 > cat3"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an SQL table in the following format:

```
id categoryname parent id
1 cat1                  0
2 cat2                  1
3 cat3                  2
4 cat4                  0
5 cat5                  4
```

how can i return a string like "cat1 > cat2 > cat3" when querying "3" or  "cat4 > cat5" when querying "4" in asp.net? It isn't always going to be three categoryies deep.. i've never done a recursive query before.. can this be done using linq?

Comment: see similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801543/oracle-connect-by-prior-equivalent-in-linq

Comment: Generating "cat1 > cat2 > cat3" from "cat3" is fetching the parents, whilst fetching "cat4 > cat5" from "cat4" is fetching the children.  Which is it you need?

Comment: I think it's just a typo and he meant *"cat4 > cat5" when querying "**5**"*.

Comment: [.NET - LINQ AsHierarchy() extension method](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance) providing a way to fetch hierarhical data using LINQ.